# If f is continuous and differentiable, and if $f(a) = f(b) = 0$ then prove that for a real number $α$ there is an $x ∈ (a,b)$ s.t. $αf(x) + f′(x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

If f is continuous on $[a, b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$, and if

$$f(a) = f(b) = 0$$
then prove that for a real number α there is an $x ∈ (a,b)$ s.t.

> $$αf(x) + f′(x) = 0$$

I know that by using Rolle's theorem, there exists a $c$ in $(a,b)$ s.t. $f'(c) = 0$ which covers for $f'(x)$, and this means that I have to prove that $αf(x) = 0$ which I think I can do by definition of continuous.

Is this sufficient to prove the question? If not, what other theorems do I need?

Comment: So, you have to prove that *for all* $\alpha \in \Bbb R$, there is $x$ such that $\alpha f(x) + f'(x) = 0$?

Comment: Yes! @AhmedHussein

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: apply Rolle's theorem to $g(x) = e^{\alpha x} f(x)$

Comment: But is my attempt at the proof correct?

Comment: @Leaf you would have to prove that for the same $x$ you obtained for which $f'(x) = 0$, $f(x) = 0$ as well; this is not always true.

Comment: Ah, I see. Could you elaborate your hint though? I don't see how it helps

Comment: @Leaf $g(a) = g(b) = 0$, so there exists $x \in (a,b)$ such that $g'(x) = 0$

Comment: Yes, but how does it relate back to αf(x)+f′(x)=0?

Comment: @Leaf $g'(x) = \alpha e^{\alpha x} f(x) + e^{\alpha x} f'(x)$. Divide both sides by $e^{\alpha x}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42835/discussion-between-leaf-and-ahmed-hussein).