# $f$ continuous in $[a,b]$, differentiable in $(a,b)$, $f(a)=f(b)=0$, then for a real $\alpha$ there is an $x \in (a,b)$ s.t. $\alpha f(x)+f'(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Show that if $f$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$, and $f(a)=f(b)=0$, then for a real $\alpha$ there is an $x \in (a,b)$ such that $\alpha f(x)+f'(x)=0$.

I believe that I am doing a logical mistake in my following solution of this problem or I am not interpreting correctly the request of the problem (English is not my first language). My solution: since the hypotheses of the mean value theorem are satisfied and it is $f(b)=f(a)=0$, there exists $x \in (a,b)$ such that $0=f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)f'(x)$. This implies $0=(b-a)f'(x)$ and, since for definition of interval $[a,b]$ it is $a<b$, hence $b-a>0$ and so $0=(b-a)f'(x)$ implies $f'(x)=0$. So $\alpha f(x)+f'(x)=0$ is true taking $\alpha=0$ for the $x \in (a,b)$ given by the mean value theorem.

I am suspicious that the problem doesn't ask for the existence of a particular real $\alpha$ that makes the identity $\alpha f(x)+f'(x)=0$ true for a $x \in (a,b)$, then I am not understanding what the problem means with "for a real $\alpha$". Can someone help explain me this better or, if I correctly understood the request but my proof is wrong, explain me why it is wrong?

Comment: I think they want it to be true for every $\alpha$, not just one:  given $\alpha$, there exists an $x$ such that....

Comment: @Randall: Thanks for the comment. So shouldn't it be written "for any real $\alpha$" instead of "for a real $\alpha$"? Am I not understanding this correctly or is this written a little imprecise?

Comment: I have no idea what they meant and whether they wrote it non-optimally or not.  I'm just guessing:  I don't have the source.

Comment: You can find lots of (correct) proofs [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Calpha%20f(x)%2Bf%27(x)%3D0%24), e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1866372

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the formulation is indeed a little imprecise and "for any real $\alpha$" would be the better formulation. "...for a real $\alpha$ ..." could mean "$\exists \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.." or "$\forall \alpha\in \mathbb{R}$...". In the first interpretation your solution is correct. In the second interpretation for a given $\alpha$ set $g(x):=\exp(\alpha x)f(x)$ on $[a,b]$ and apply the mean value theorem to $g$.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this is true for al $\alpha$. We may assume that $f'(a)\not=0$, as well as $f'(b)$, otherwise $a$ (or $b$) does the job. Changing $f$ to $-f$, we may even assume that $f'(a)>0$. Let $b_1$ be the first $0$ of $f$, $b_1=Min (x/f(x)=0$. Note that $b_1>a$, and $f$ is $>0$ on $[a,b_1]$, so that $f'(b_1)\leq 0$. Now, if $g(x)=\alpha f(x)+f'(x)$, $g(a)>0,g(b_1)\leq0$, so somewhere inbetween, $g(x)=0$.